# What weight punching bag should I get?

Tags: martial-arts, boxing

I'm looking to buy a heavy punching bag to practice karate and possibly teach myself some boxing. I'm 15 and I weigh about 140lbs and I was wondering what punching bag weight I should choose. I heard that it's best to use a punching bag that is half your weight, so for me that would be a 70lb bag, but I don't really know for sure if that's what I should do.

Comment: Honestly if you wanna start with boxing, you should seek a trainer first rathert han a punching bag

Comment: You could also ask on https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/